# ./runInstaller Oracle 19c - Unable to verify the graphical display setup

Tags: linux, hadoop, java-8, centos, oracle19c

Problem to install Oracle 19c on CentOS 8.

```
[hadoop@localhost dbhome_1]$ sudo ./runInstaller
[sudo] password for hadoop: 
ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.
/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/perl/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[hadoop@localhost dbhome_1]$
```

- X running?

```
[hadoop@localhost dbhome_1]$ ps -e | grep X 
   2171 tty1     00:00:00 Xwayland
   2578 tty2     00:00:22 Xwayland
```

- Can this error occur because I'm using localhost.domain?

Environmental vars:

```
# Java 
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

# Oracle
export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
export ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
export ORA_INVENTORY=/u01/app/oraInventory
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export DATA_DIR=/u02/oradata
export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
```

- /etc/hosts file configuration according to ifconfig:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.15.3 localhost.localdomain
```

- IP adress 192.168.15.3 was extracted from ifconfig:

```
[hadoop@localhost dbhome_1]$ ifconfig
wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.15.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
        inet6 2804:431:c7c0:1c46:10be:3dcc:8f5f:c204  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::afe8:386a:34f:c943  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a4:63:a1:05:f1:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 256300  bytes 353610021 (337.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 28  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40392  bytes 5541776 (5.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- Java version:

```
[hadoop@localhost dbhome_1]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

What solved the graphical display error was to change the devicename from "localhost" to "dataserver" and use another username - "oracle" with groupname called "oinstall".

Additionally, I changed the ownership from the dbhome_1 from "root" to "oracle:oinstall" username and groupname.

The libnsl.so.1 library was easily installed with sudo dnf install libnsl.